# jpa convert scalar values from native sql to entity

Tags: jpa

Is there a way in JPA to convert random select clause values using createNativeQuery to a domain object. The domain object is not managed

I have the following sql query

```
select name, count(*) as cnt, sum(average_events)/count(*) as avg_events from (complex subquery)
```

I want to convert the values a,b,c into a domain object with three instance variables a, b and c. This domain object is not managed by JPA and hence does not have @Entity and no corresponding table.

Currently I am doing the following, which returns a list of objects.

```
 Query query = objectManager.getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(sqlStr);
 List resultList = query.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this syntax:

```
SELECT new foo.MyCustomObject(a, b, c) FROM ...
```

Where `MyCustomObject` is any class with matching consdtructor:

```
public class MyCustomObject {
  private final String name;
  private final int cnt;
  private final float avg;
  public MyCustomObject(String name, int cnt, float avg) {
    this.name = name;
    this.cnt = cnt;
    this.avg = avg;
  }
  //...getters
}
```

Scala bonus: equivalent class:

```
class MyCustomObject(name: String, cnt: Int, avg: Float)
//no, actually that's it
```

Comment: @user373201: Have you tried it? the `SELECT new` syntax will create an object for you and call specified constructor. This means that `query.getResultList()` will return a `List<MyCustomObject>` rather than a `List<Object[]>`. Also `MyCustomObject` can be *any* object having matching constructor. I updated field names of `MyCustomObject` so they fit naming used in your query.

Answer (score 2):

Just pass in the "resultClass" to the createNativeQuery call. Certainly works in DataNucleus JPA.

Comment: true, also works with Hibernate and does not need SELECT NEW() with the additional boilerplate code necessary for the constructor...

see "Native SQL Queries" in http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/vasiliev-jpql-087123.html